# Factorial spacing inside equation

Tags: math-mode

Good day,

My minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\hat{d}=\frac{(d+n)!}{n!d!}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image: Result of MWE]

Now I don't like the spacing for the term: "n!d!". I'd prefer a bit more space between 'n' and '!' and between 'd' and '!'.

Any ideas?

Comment: A short solution would be forcing a single space between them by using `\ `, like this: `{n\ ! d\ !}`

Comment: That would be incorrect. In case the `!` is followed by an ordinary symbol, add a thin space: `n!\,d!`, but don't detach the `!` from the symbol preceding it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's incorrect to detach the `!` meaning “factorial” from the symbol preceding it, because it's a modifier similar to a prime or a subscript and is not a punctuation symbol.

In case you have a factorial followed by an ordinary symbol (not a relation or operation symbol), it's good practice to add a thin space after it:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\[
\makebox[4em]{Good:}
\hat{d}=\frac{(d+n)!}{n!\,d!}
\]
\[
\makebox[4em]{Bad:}
\hat{d}=\frac{(d+n)\,!}{n\,!d\,!}
\]
\end{document}
```

I've also shown what would happen when detaching the factorial symbol, in order to demonstrate it would be wrong.

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with TeX's ifttt syntax but wouldn't it be possible and useful to create a macro for this, say `factorial`, which checks automatically what follows after it and adds a thin space if appropriate?

Comment: @PacificOrion The main problem is deciding when a space is appropriate and this is the main reason why it's declared as ordinary rather than punctuation. Having a space or not depends on several considerations.

Comment: What would those be? Wouldn't adding a thin space whenever `\factorial` was followed by something other than `}` be a good start?

Comment: @PacificOrion When `\frac{n!}{2}` is processed, `!` won't be followed by `}` any more.

Comment: Ah? I guess I don't know enough about TeX's parsing. Could `\factorial` check the user's input rather than the processed stuff?

Comment: @PacificOrion No, it doesn't work like this. For instance, `\frac{\factorial{n}}{2}` would become `{\begingroup \factorial{n}\endgroup\over 2}`. TeX (usually) works from outside to inside; the “usually” is for some very special situation, not strictly connected with macro expansion.

Comment: Okay. This seems more like an issue of implementation, really.

Answer (score -2):

```
\hat{d}=\frac{(d+n)!}{n!\,d!}
```

Instead of this use

```
\begin{equation}
\hat{d}=\frac{(d+n)!}{n! \enspace d!} 
\end{equation}
```

It will work.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  This is an excessively large space to add, the `\,` space is typographically better.